# How to retrieve the image from contacts in the mobile(Android with PhoneGap) using java script

Tags: android, image, cordova, contacts

Hai In my phoneGap Android Application i retrived the contact name and phone number by using this [Tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts) ,now  i want to retrive the images from the contacts.Is it possible?anyBody Kindly help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read again the article you provided, the `Contact` object you are already using includes a `.photos[]` property which includes all photos attached to the contact - whether as a URL, base64 or else...

Hope this helps